# Can I earn a specific badge more than once?

Tags: support, badges

I am just curious. I see users on gaming.stackexchange with 100+ bronze badges, so can I earn a specific bronze badge more than once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are various badges that can be awarded multiple times. If you have a specific badge in mind, you can click through to its description on the [list of badges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges) to see if it's something you can earn more than once.

Badges which can be awarded multiple times state so in their description, like in the case of the [Announcer badge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/189/announcer):

> Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses. **This badge can be awarded multiple times.**

In this case, you can receive the badge more than once by meeting the criteria with links to different questions.

Comment: cool.thank you very much